# Can claw caps (like Softpaws) cause infections?

Tags: cats, safety, grooming

I heard someone assert that claw caps (like Softpaws) can cause infections, but I've used them for several years without any issue.

What is the risk of infection? Are there any ways to eliminate/reduce the risk?

Answer (score 1):

My cat Mama has been using them for a few months and one of her claw caps has become embedded in her toe causing an infection. She doesn’t appear to be in any pain and she walks on it fine but her toe has turned black around the affected area and the cap won’t come off. I’m scheduled to take her to the vet this week, as we just noticed it recently. But I will probably never use them again unless the vet advises we were applying them wrong (we followed the instructions and it’s pretty self-explanatory) or something indicating it wasn’t the claw caps fault. I wish you luck in finding answers!

Comment: can you please add more information,as the answer is now it only answers the question partly.wellcome to pets